# why my other table th height changing while i want to change one specific th?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have an html table, and when I change plan c th, the height of the other th changes as well.

I only want to change one specific th height, that of the plan C table. The other heights will remain constant. When i trying to change height of plan c th, other th height also changing. I tried it with pseudo-class. But still havaing issues

This is how I want it. [image]

My code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Table</title>
    <style>
        .table-main {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 1080px;
            border-spacing: 6px;
            border-collapse: separate;
            overflow-x: auto;
            border: 0 !important;
            margin: 20px auto;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        }
        .table-main tr:first-child th:first-child {
            border: 0;
            background: transparent;
        }
        .table-main tr:first-child th {
            background: linear-gradient( 90deg, #007bc4 0%, #007bc4 0%, rgb(0, 102, 153) 100%);
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-top-right-radius: 12px;
        }
        .table-main tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {
            border-top-left-radius: 12px;
        }
        .table-main tr:last-child td {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
        }
        .table-main tr:nth-child(odd) td {
           background-color: #eaeaea; 
        }
        .table-main th,
        .table-main td {
            border: 2px solid #fff;
            padding-top: 4px;
            padding-bottom: 4px;
            padding-left: 14px;
            padding-right: 14px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .table-main tr td {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #666666;
            background: #F7F7F7;
            min-width: 140px;
            height: 44px !important;
        }
        .table-main tr td:first-child {
            text-align: start;
            font-weight: bolder;
            width: 220px;
        }
        .table-main tr:first-child th {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 600;
            line-height: normal;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
       
        .table-main tr td:nth-child(2),
        .table-main tr td:nth-child(3),
        .table-main tr td:nth-child(4),
        .table-main tr td:nth-child(5) {
            width: 160px;
        }
        .table-main tr:last-child td:first-child {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        .table-main tr:last-child td {
            font-size: 30px;
            padding-top: 14px;
            color: #666666;
            background: #F7F7F7;
        }
        .table-main tr:last-child td .price-btn {
            padding: var(--25, 10px) var(--6, 24px);
            border-radius: var(--rounded-full, 9999px);
            font-size: 16px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 300;
            line-height: normal;
            margin-top: 14px;
            margin-bottom: 14px;
            color: #fff;
            background: linear-gradient( 90deg, #007bc4 0%, #007bc4 0%, rgb(0, 102, 153) 100%);
            border: 1px solid #007bc4;
            transition: 0.3s ease;
        }
        .table-main tr:last-child td .price-btn:hover {
            background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(0, 102, 153) 0%, rgb(0, 102, 153) 0%, rgb(0, 102, 153) 100%);
            cursor: pointer;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
        <table class="table-main">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Plan A</th>
                <th>Plan B</th>
                <th>Plan C</th>
                <th>Plan D</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Description One Here</td>
                <td>1 User</td>
                <td>3 User</td>
                <td>20 User</td>
                <td>3 User</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Another Description</td>
                <td>1 User</td>
                <td>3 User</td>
                <td>20 User</td>
                <td>3 User</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some Other Text</td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Description Number 2</td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 365.717 365" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><g fill="#f44336"><path d="M356.34 296.348 69.727 9.734c-12.5-12.5-32.766-12.5-45.247 0L9.375 24.816c-12.5 12.504-12.5 32.77 0 45.25L295.988 356.68c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0l15.082-15.082c12.524-12.48 12.524-32.75.02-45.25zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path><path d="M295.988 9.734 9.375 296.348c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.77 0 45.25l15.082 15.082c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0L356.34 70.086c12.504-12.5 12.504-32.766 0-45.246L341.258 9.758c-12.5-12.524-32.766-12.524-45.27-.024zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path></g></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 365.717 365" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><g fill="#f44336"><path d="M356.34 296.348 69.727 9.734c-12.5-12.5-32.766-12.5-45.247 0L9.375 24.816c-12.5 12.504-12.5 32.77 0 45.25L295.988 356.68c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0l15.082-15.082c12.524-12.48 12.524-32.75.02-45.25zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path><path d="M295.988 9.734 9.375 296.348c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.77 0 45.25l15.082 15.082c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0L356.34 70.086c12.504-12.5 12.504-32.766 0-45.246L341.258 9.758c-12.5-12.524-32.766-12.524-45.27-.024zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path></g></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 365.717 365" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><g fill="#f44336"><path d="M356.34 296.348 69.727 9.734c-12.5-12.5-32.766-12.5-45.247 0L9.375 24.816c-12.5 12.504-12.5 32.77 0 45.25L295.988 356.68c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0l15.082-15.082c12.524-12.48 12.524-32.75.02-45.25zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path><path d="M295.988 9.734 9.375 296.348c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.77 0 45.25l15.082 15.082c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0L356.34 70.086c12.504-12.5 12.504-32.766 0-45.246L341.258 9.758c-12.5-12.524-32.766-12.524-45.27-.024zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path></g></g></svg></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Your Text Here</td>
                <td>100 emails</td>
                <td>200 emails</td>
                <td>Unlimited</td>
                <td>200 emails</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Description Number 4</td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 365.717 365" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><g fill="#f44336"><path d="M356.34 296.348 69.727 9.734c-12.5-12.5-32.766-12.5-45.247 0L9.375 24.816c-12.5 12.504-12.5 32.77 0 45.25L295.988 356.68c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0l15.082-15.082c12.524-12.48 12.524-32.75.02-45.25zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path><path d="M295.988 9.734 9.375 296.348c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.77 0 45.25l15.082 15.082c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0L356.34 70.086c12.504-12.5 12.504-32.766 0-45.246L341.258 9.758c-12.5-12.524-32.766-12.524-45.27-.024zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path></g></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 365.717 365" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><g fill="#f44336"><path d="M356.34 296.348 69.727 9.734c-12.5-12.5-32.766-12.5-45.247 0L9.375 24.816c-12.5 12.504-12.5 32.77 0 45.25L295.988 356.68c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0l15.082-15.082c12.524-12.48 12.524-32.75.02-45.25zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path><path d="M295.988 9.734 9.375 296.348c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.77 0 45.25l15.082 15.082c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0L356.34 70.086c12.504-12.5 12.504-32.766 0-45.246L341.258 9.758c-12.5-12.524-32.766-12.524-45.27-.024zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path></g></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 365.717 365" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><g fill="#f44336"><path d="M356.34 296.348 69.727 9.734c-12.5-12.5-32.766-12.5-45.247 0L9.375 24.816c-12.5 12.504-12.5 32.77 0 45.25L295.988 356.68c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0l15.082-15.082c12.524-12.48 12.524-32.75.02-45.25zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path><path d="M295.988 9.734 9.375 296.348c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.77 0 45.25l15.082 15.082c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0L356.34 70.086c12.504-12.5 12.504-32.766 0-45.246L341.258 9.758c-12.5-12.524-32.766-12.524-45.27-.024zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path></g></g></svg></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Other Text</td>
                <td>No Support</td>
                <td>Email Support</td>
                <td>Phone Support</td>
                <td>Email Support</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>The Last Text</td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 365.717 365" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><g fill="#f44336"><path d="M356.34 296.348 69.727 9.734c-12.5-12.5-32.766-12.5-45.247 0L9.375 24.816c-12.5 12.504-12.5 32.77 0 45.25L295.988 356.68c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0l15.082-15.082c12.524-12.48 12.524-32.75.02-45.25zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path><path d="M295.988 9.734 9.375 296.348c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.77 0 45.25l15.082 15.082c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0L356.34 70.086c12.504-12.5 12.504-32.766 0-45.246L341.258 9.758c-12.5-12.524-32.766-12.524-45.27-.024zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path></g></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>&#36;14<br><a href="#"><button class="price-btn">Buy Now</button></a></td>
                <td>&#36;28<br><a href="#"><button class="price-btn">Buy Now</button></a></td>
                <td>&#36;36<br><a href="#"><button class="price-btn">Buy Now</button></a></td>
                <td>&#36;53<br><a href="#"><button class="price-btn">Buy Now</button></a></td>
            </tr>


        </table>

    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML tables will have the rows' height aligned vertically all the time. If I were to code this I would make the top and bottom rows as divs inside of the table tags, and then set that row to vertically align either by the top or the bottom.

Here is how I would edit your code to make it work the way your screenshot is. Please note I reordered your CSS and simplified it a bit.

```css
/* table outline */
        .table-main {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 1080px;
            border-spacing: 6px;
            border-collapse: separate;
            overflow-x: auto;
            border: 0 !important;
            margin: 20px auto;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        }


        /* tr styles */
        /* th styles */
        .table-main tr:first-child th {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            vertical-align: bottom;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 600;
            line-height: normal;
        }
        .table-main tr:first-child th:first-child {
            border: 0;
            background: transparent;
        }

        /* td styles */
        .table-main th,
        .table-main td {
            border: 2px solid #fff;
            padding-top: 4px;
            padding-bottom: 4px;
            padding-left: 14px;
            padding-right: 14px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .table-main tr td {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #666666;
            background: #F7F7F7;
            min-width: 140px;
            height: 44px !important;
        }
        .table-main tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {
            border-top-left-radius: 12px;
        }
        .table-main tr:nth-child(odd) td {
           background-color: #eaeaea; 
        }
        .table-main tr:last-child td {
            padding: 0;
            background: none;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        .table-main tr td:first-child {
            text-align: start;
            font-weight: bolder;
            width: 220px;
        }
        .table-main tr:last-child td:first-child {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        .table-main tr td:nth-child(2),
        .table-main tr td:nth-child(3),
        .table-main tr td:nth-child(4),
        .table-main tr td:nth-child(5) {
            width: 160px;
        }

        /* th's nested divs */
        .table-main tr:first-child th div {
            background: linear-gradient( 90deg, #007bc4 0%, #007bc4 0%, rgb(0, 102, 153) 100%);
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-top-right-radius: 12px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .table-main tr:first-child th:nth-child(4) div {
            background: linear-gradient( 90deg, #AFE1AF 0%, #AFE1AF 0%, #50C878 100%);
            padding-top: 30px;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            color: #355E3B;
        }

        /* td's nested divs */
        .table-main tr:last-child td div {
            font-size: 30px;
            padding-top: 14px;
            color: #666666;
            background: #F7F7F7;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .table-main tr:last-child td:nth-child(4) div {
            background: linear-gradient( 90deg, #AFE1AF 0%, #AFE1AF 0%, #50C878 100%);
            padding-top: 30px;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            color: #355E3B;
        }

        /* price btn */
        .table-main tr:last-child td .price-btn {
            padding: var(--25, 10px) var(--6, 24px);
            border-radius: var(--rounded-full, 9999px);
            font-size: 16px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 300;
            line-height: normal;
            margin-top: 14px;
            margin-bottom: 14px;
            color: #fff;
            background: linear-gradient( 90deg, #007bc4 0%, #007bc4 0%, rgb(0, 102, 153) 100%);
            border: 1px solid #007bc4;
            transition: 0.3s ease;
        }
        .table-main tr:last-child td .price-btn:hover {
            background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(0, 102, 153) 0%, rgb(0, 102, 153) 0%, rgb(0, 102, 153) 100%);
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Table</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
        <table class="table-main">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th><div>Plan A</div></th>
                <th><div>Plan B</div></th>
                <th><div>Plan C</div></th>
                <th><div>Plan D</div></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Description One Here</td>
                <td>1 User</td>
                <td>3 User</td>
                <td>20 User</td>
                <td>3 User</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Another Description</td>
                <td>1 User</td>
                <td>3 User</td>
                <td>20 User</td>
                <td>3 User</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some Other Text</td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Description Number 2</td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 365.717 365" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><g fill="#f44336"><path d="M356.34 296.348 69.727 9.734c-12.5-12.5-32.766-12.5-45.247 0L9.375 24.816c-12.5 12.504-12.5 32.77 0 45.25L295.988 356.68c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0l15.082-15.082c12.524-12.48 12.524-32.75.02-45.25zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path><path d="M295.988 9.734 9.375 296.348c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.77 0 45.25l15.082 15.082c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0L356.34 70.086c12.504-12.5 12.504-32.766 0-45.246L341.258 9.758c-12.5-12.524-32.766-12.524-45.27-.024zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path></g></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 365.717 365" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><g fill="#f44336"><path d="M356.34 296.348 69.727 9.734c-12.5-12.5-32.766-12.5-45.247 0L9.375 24.816c-12.5 12.504-12.5 32.77 0 45.25L295.988 356.68c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0l15.082-15.082c12.524-12.48 12.524-32.75.02-45.25zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path><path d="M295.988 9.734 9.375 296.348c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.77 0 45.25l15.082 15.082c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0L356.34 70.086c12.504-12.5 12.504-32.766 0-45.246L341.258 9.758c-12.5-12.524-32.766-12.524-45.27-.024zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path></g></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 365.717 365" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><g fill="#f44336"><path d="M356.34 296.348 69.727 9.734c-12.5-12.5-32.766-12.5-45.247 0L9.375 24.816c-12.5 12.504-12.5 32.77 0 45.25L295.988 356.68c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0l15.082-15.082c12.524-12.48 12.524-32.75.02-45.25zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path><path d="M295.988 9.734 9.375 296.348c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.77 0 45.25l15.082 15.082c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0L356.34 70.086c12.504-12.5 12.504-32.766 0-45.246L341.258 9.758c-12.5-12.524-32.766-12.524-45.27-.024zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path></g></g></svg></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Your Text Here</td>
                <td>100 emails</td>
                <td>200 emails</td>
                <td>Unlimited</td>
                <td>200 emails</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Description Number 4</td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 365.717 365" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><g fill="#f44336"><path d="M356.34 296.348 69.727 9.734c-12.5-12.5-32.766-12.5-45.247 0L9.375 24.816c-12.5 12.504-12.5 32.77 0 45.25L295.988 356.68c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0l15.082-15.082c12.524-12.48 12.524-32.75.02-45.25zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path><path d="M295.988 9.734 9.375 296.348c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.77 0 45.25l15.082 15.082c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0L356.34 70.086c12.504-12.5 12.504-32.766 0-45.246L341.258 9.758c-12.5-12.524-32.766-12.524-45.27-.024zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path></g></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 365.717 365" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><g fill="#f44336"><path d="M356.34 296.348 69.727 9.734c-12.5-12.5-32.766-12.5-45.247 0L9.375 24.816c-12.5 12.504-12.5 32.77 0 45.25L295.988 356.68c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0l15.082-15.082c12.524-12.48 12.524-32.75.02-45.25zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path><path d="M295.988 9.734 9.375 296.348c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.77 0 45.25l15.082 15.082c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0L356.34 70.086c12.504-12.5 12.504-32.766 0-45.246L341.258 9.758c-12.5-12.524-32.766-12.524-45.27-.024zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path></g></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 365.717 365" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><g fill="#f44336"><path d="M356.34 296.348 69.727 9.734c-12.5-12.5-32.766-12.5-45.247 0L9.375 24.816c-12.5 12.504-12.5 32.77 0 45.25L295.988 356.68c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0l15.082-15.082c12.524-12.48 12.524-32.75.02-45.25zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path><path d="M295.988 9.734 9.375 296.348c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.77 0 45.25l15.082 15.082c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0L356.34 70.086c12.504-12.5 12.504-32.766 0-45.246L341.258 9.758c-12.5-12.524-32.766-12.524-45.27-.024zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path></g></g></svg></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Other Text</td>
                <td>No Support</td>
                <td>Email Support</td>
                <td>Phone Support</td>
                <td>Email Support</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>The Last Text</td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 365.717 365" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><g fill="#f44336"><path d="M356.34 296.348 69.727 9.734c-12.5-12.5-32.766-12.5-45.247 0L9.375 24.816c-12.5 12.504-12.5 32.77 0 45.25L295.988 356.68c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0l15.082-15.082c12.524-12.48 12.524-32.75.02-45.25zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path><path d="M295.988 9.734 9.375 296.348c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.77 0 45.25l15.082 15.082c12.504 12.5 32.77 12.5 45.25 0L356.34 70.086c12.504-12.5 12.504-32.766 0-45.246L341.258 9.758c-12.5-12.524-32.766-12.524-45.27-.024zm0 0" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#f44336" class=""></path></g></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
                <td><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="34" height="36" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" class=""><g><path d="M21.634 47.186c-1.893-2.126-3.422-4.206-4.899-6.22a35.467 35.467 0 0 1-3.494-5.845c-.61-1.248-.88-2.51.441-3.323 3.787-2.327 4.563-.105 6.62 2.473 1.22 1.528 3.02 4.047 4.147 5.639 1.077 1.52 2.39-1.223 2.913-1.998 1.863-2.75 6.703-9.486 8.704-11.975 1.899-2.364 8.028-8.985 9.17-10.038.973-.897 3.027-2.863 4.408-1.778 1.45 1.14 2.16 3.307 1.14 4.716-1.777 2.453-4.567 4.786-6.498 7.122-3.908 4.728-7.608 9.824-11.16 14.899-1.207 1.724-2.901 4.612-3.953 6.482-1.968 3.499-3.696 4.164-7.54-.154z" fill="#007bc4" opacity="1" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></svg></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><div>&#36;14<br><a href="#"><button class="price-btn">Buy Now</button></a></div></td>
                <td><div>&#36;28<br><a href="#"><button class="price-btn">Buy Now</button></a></div></td>
                <td><div>&#36;36<br><a href="#"><button class="price-btn">Buy Now</button></a></div></td>
                <td><div>&#36;53<br><a href="#"><button class="price-btn">Buy Now</button></a></div></td>
            </tr>


        </table>

    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```